# How do I get a users online status via the slack api?

Tags: slack-api

the users active/away status does not appear to be listed here:
https://api.slack.com/types/user

is there another method to query this information that I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you noticed it by now, but there is a method named users.getPresence in the Slack API.

Example of querying the API, given that you have created a token (token=xoxp-313xxxxxx-313xxxxxx-313xxxxxx-xxxxxx) and you are looking for the user with the ID U03xxxxxx.

```
curl -X POST https://slack.com/api/users.getPresence 
     --data "token=xoxp-313xxxxxx-313xxxxxx-313xxxxxx-xxxxxx&user=U03xxxxxx"
```

Response:

```
{"ok":true,"presence":"away"}
```

Note that you can get user ids, with the method users.list or users.info.

REF: https://api.slack.com/methods

Comment: Thanks! Looked for curl usage examples in official Slack API docs, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's the `status` key on `user` objects returned from

```
https://slack.com/api/users.info
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easier way for this > get all user presence status (up to 1000 users) quickly is the users.list method.

https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info

https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=xoxp-173888888-XXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYY-ZZZZZZZZ&presence=true&pretty=1

Please don't forget to read the documentation, sometimes the limit at 200.